# G-Wan / Ngnix / Squid / Varnish as HTTP Live Streaming Reverse Proxy

Tags: http-live-streaming, http-caching

I'm planing to build a caching reverse proxy for HTTP Live Stream(Apple HLS)
For my situation, I configured size of each segment file will be about 500-700KB.I read a lot of article about the performance review for popular Web Server software. But all of them are testing small-file-size caching. So is there anybody has experience about build cache server for large file(honestly, 700KB is not too large I think)? Or any review article I missed you can provide to me?

I think I can get answers from review article before. But maybe I list my questions below.

1. If I increase the number of total segments, will this cause performance decrease(since search take longer time) and how serious it is?
2. If I want to maximize the throughput(Let's say 1Gbps I got), what server software and CPU I should choose?(This is as same as asking which server software can provide highest throughput)
3. As jeremy reminds me, caching time will really affect the hit rate and performance. For caching segments, should I set the caching time to be the rotation time?(exp. 00-99.ts@10s each .ts file should be changed 990s after last time updated, so rotation time is 990s) Or any better suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

500-700KB files are still very small, I've had great success with both NGinx and Varnish for this exact task.

You will want to make sure you have a fairly large expiration time on your .ts files (you want cache hits on these).  And you want to set your expiration on .m3u8 files to be less than 1/2 of your segment length.

This is especially true if you are going to be using a CDN, since the CDN will honor the cache control headers (typically) and you will want to limit the number of requests back to the origin.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and teaching. I've think a lot about caching time. But for my case, I don't need CDN because I want to limit the broadcasting in 2 cities due to legal concern. However, I want to maximize the throughput for each node due to lack of fund. So I want a detailed review about the web server software I mentioned and what configuration will affect the performance. For example, if I increase the number of total segments, will this cause performance decrease(since search take longer time) and how serious it is?

Comment: There are a lot of related factors, one big one is time to start.  In many implementations the starting segment needs to be downloaded completely before starting playback.  The other consideration is how far behind live you are.  Apple officially recommends 10 second segments, partially due to CDN complications.  I've successfully used values ranging from 2-10 seconds without much issue.